# Probability - Calculating the probability of choosing 5 cards with 4 different suits fail

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the probability of taking from a regular deck of cards (52) 5 cards with 4 different suits, my go:

first we think about picking 'diamond' (just to make it more simple) it is: $\frac{13}{52}$
second we think about picking 'heart': $\frac{13}{51}$
same thing for the two other suits: $\frac{13}{50}$ and $\frac{13}{49}$ respectively.
The fifth card needs to be the same one of the suits, so: $\frac{12}{48}$ because we took each card from each suit, so we have only $12$ remaining in that same suit.

But we have to consider the order that we draw the cards, so we multiply by $5!$

And we have my final answer of: $5! \cdot \frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{51} \cdot \frac{13}{50} \cdot \frac{13}{49} \cdot \frac{12}{48}$

Sadly, this answer is only **half** the real answer: $\approx 0.26375$  mine gives:  $\approx 0.13187$

Where does the $ \cdot 2$ need to come from? I don't see another orientation other than the suit we pick the second card to be of, so we don't need to multiply by $2$ but by $4C2 = 6$ and that gives me an answer that times $3$ larger than the real one, so in that case, where does the $\frac{1}{3}$ need to come from?

Thank you!

Comment: You have two mistakes which combine to give you half the right answer. First, in your last step, any suit will work if you have $4$ different suits in the first $4$ draws -- so $12/48$ makes your answer $1/4$ of what it "should be". Second, the method of choosing one card of each suit and then an arbitrary fifth card over-counts by a factor of two, because any hand, say 3S 3H 5D 7C 9C, gets counted twice, once with 7C in the first group of $4$ and once with 9C in the first group. $2*(1/4) = 1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the "correct" hand should contain two cards of a suit and one card of each of the other 3 suits. There are $\binom41$ ways to choose the suit with the double, and 
$\binom{13}2$ ways to choose the double out of the suit. Therefore the overall number of "correct" hands is:
$$
\binom41\binom{13}2\binom{13}1^3.
$$
Dividing this by the overall number of hands: $\binom{52}5$ you obtain the correct probability.

You way fails because of two reasons: first you double-count the hands and second your miss the factor 4 because the "last" card may be of any of 4 suits.

Comment: I see now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could have picked either of the cards of the same suit first, so you’re counting each admissible hand exactly twice.

Comment: So, because theoretically I could have picked the card that has the same suit first, and not last I need to multiply everything by 2?

Comment: @OUR: No, the opposite: Because of that, you need to divide by $2$, since you double-counted.

Comment: But then I get an answer that is smaller by a factor of 4 :(

Comment: @OUR You should still multiply the result by the number of suits (see also my answer).

Comment: @user Hey, I saw your answer but it is different at it uses "choosing" $4C1$ etc.. and I need to find where my own way fails

Comment: @OUR I added the explanation where your way fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that the problem could be solved by using the hypergeometric multivariate distribution

P(x,y,z,t) = [ 13Cx 13Cy 13Cz 13Ct ] / 52C5

where x,y,z,t are the random variables associated to the four disjoint sets of the suites

as the only 4 possible configurations of the random variables compatible with the requested probability are the following

x  y  z  t

2  1  1  1
1  2  1  1
1  1  2  1
1  1  1  2

we find:

P = P(2,1,1,1)+P(1,2,1,1)+P(1,1,2,1)+P(1,1,1,2) = [ 13C2 13C1 13C1 13C1 ] x 4 / 52C5 = 26%